# How to find id and password in mongodb with java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have my `sampledb database` and `user collection` and I made some entries which are as follows. I want to perform a query with multiple fields and if all the fields are matching then return `true` otherwise `false`

```
user
{
    "_id": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "XYZ",
    "last_name": "PQR",
    "password": "xyzxyz",
}
```

How do I write a method which performs the query through `user collection` with `email and pwd` and returns `true` only when the `email` matches with `_id` and `password` matches with `pwd`.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find that if there is a document containing the `_id` having a password field `pwd` is as follows

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id",email);
query.append("Password",pwd);
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.put("_id",2);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query,obj);
return cursor.hasNext();
```

Comment: Could be simplified to `return cursor.hasNext()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see if a document exists with the given `_id` and `password`:

```
public boolean userExists(String email, String password) {
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", email).append("pwd", password);
    return client.getDB("sampledb").getCollection("user").findOne(query) != null;
}
```

Comment: The document user is containing the email and pwd along with some other data. And i want to find the document which contains this email as _id and password as pwd.

Comment: @SatishPatel But you use the `password` key in your example document, no?

Comment: Yeah, right. I think I am doing something wring in other class. I'll update you.

Comment: I tried the solution you provided but it didn't work well. The way I solved is answered below. BTW Thanks for the effort. :)